# C - Rock, Paper, Scissors scoreboard Issues

Tags: c

Language: **C**

**Situation:** Our professor has us making a rock, paper, scissors code with separate functions from the main and also including a "switch" statement, "for" loop, and an "if...else" statement.

**Problem:** The program works for the most part but fails to display the correct amounts for the scoreboard when quitting. It seems to ignore everything before hand and default back to the original defined value "0"

**My C code is here below:**

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "time.h"

// Rock
int rock(int comp, int Tie, int Cwon, int Pwon) {
  if(comp==1) {
    printf("\nTie!\n");
    Tie++;
  } else if(comp==2) {
    printf("\nYou picked Rock, the computer picked Paper.\nPaper covers Rock, the computer wins!\n");
    Cwon++;
  } else if(comp==3) {
    printf("\nYou picked Rock, the computer picked Scissors.\nRock breaks Scissors, you win!\n");
    Pwon++;
  } else {
    printf("Error");
  }
    return Tie, Cwon, Pwon;
}

// Paper
int paper(int comp, int Tie, int Cwon, int Pwon) {
  if(comp==1) {
    printf("\nYou picked Paper, the computer picked Rock.\nPaper covers Rock, you win!\n");
    Pwon++;
  } else if(comp==2) {
    printf("\nTie!\n");
    Tie++;
  } else if(comp==3) {
    printf("\nYou picked Paper, the computer picked Scissors.\nScissors cut Paper, the computer wins!\n");
    Cwon++;
  } else {
    printf("Error");
  }
    return Tie, Cwon, Pwon;
}

// Scissors
int scissors(int comp, int Tie, int Cwon, int Pwon) {
  if(comp==1) {
    printf("\nYou picked Scissors, the computer picked Rock.\nRock breaks Scissors, the computer wins!\n");
    Cwon++;
  } else if(comp==2) {
    printf("\nYou picked Scissors, the computer picked Paper.\nScissors cut Paper, you win!\n");
    Pwon++;
  } else if(comp==3) {
    printf("\nTie!\n");
    Tie++;
  } else {
    printf("Error");
  }
  return Tie, Cwon, Pwon;
}

// Score Display
int score(int Pwon, int Cwon, int Tie) {
  printf("\nYou won %d times, the computer won %d times and it was a tie %d times.\nThank you for playing!\n", Pwon, Cwon, Tie);
}

// playCases w/ Switch
int playCases(char input, int comp, int Tie, int Cwon, int Pwon, int i) {
  switch(input) {
    case 'R' :
    case 'r' : 
       rock(comp, Tie, Cwon, Pwon);
       break;
    case 'P' :
    case 'p' : 
       paper(comp, Tie, Cwon, Pwon);
       break;
    case 'S' :
    case 's' : 
       scissors(comp, Tie, Cwon, Pwon);
       break;
    case 'Q' :
    case 'q' :
       score(Pwon, Cwon, Tie);
       i=999;
       break;
    default :
       printf("Error: Invalid choice, try again.");
       break;
  }
  return Tie, Cwon, Pwon;
}

// Flush
void flushScanf(int input) {
    char r;
    while((r = getchar()) != '\n' && r != EOF);
}

// Main Function
int main(void) {
  char input;
  int Cwon=0, Pwon=0, Tie=0;
  printf("Let's play a game of Rock/Paper/Scissors\n");

  //For Loop
  for(int i=1; i<999;++i) {
    printf("\nEnter the r, p, s, or q (for quit): ");
    scanf("%c", &input);
    flushScanf(input);
    int comp=rand()%3+1;
    playCases(input, comp, Tie, Cwon, Pwon, i);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I am still relatively new to coding so I apologize if my code seems like a mess and not condensed as it should be.

Comment: You cannot return three integers when the return type is int.

Comment: Consider using a single variable that holds exclusive states. `enum` would be good. For example `enum result { LOST, WON, TIE, ERR };` Aside: `#include "stdio.h"` is usually `#include <stdio.h>` your version instructs the compiler to find your own versions before looking in the library.

Comment: Are you in the same class with the guy who asked this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48995758/c-variable-increment-not-working-rock-paper-scissors

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have passed your counters **by value**. as the term implies, only the value of the value of the variable is copied, and the relationship to the original variable is lost.

In C++ you could pass them by reference, but in C you will have to pass them by pointer if you want to update them, or think of a way to use the return value to return the one result, and deal with it in the main code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems. Learn how to pass variables by pointers. If you do so, you can modify the values inside your functions.

```
 int paper(int comp, int Tie, int Cwon, int Pwon) {
```

replace with:

```
int paper(int comp, int *Tie, int *Cwon, int *Pwon) {
//...
 (*Cwon)++;
//...
}
```

You cannot return multiply values like this:

```
 return Tie, Cwon, Pwon;
```

As I mention, use pointers and modify the values after pointer is dereferenced by `*` operator.

This is small example for your consideration. Notice that `num` does not change outside the function scissors.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void scissors(int num, int *Tie, int *Cwon, int *Pwon) {

     num++;

     (*Tie)++;
     (*Cwon)++;
     (*Pwon)++;
}

int main() {
    int num = 0;
    int Tie = 1;
    int Cwon= 2;
    int Pwon= 3;

    scissors(num, &Tie, &Cwon, &Pwon);
    printf("num= %d Tie= %d Cwon= %d  Pwon= %d \n", num, Tie, Cwon, Pwon );

    scissors(num, &Tie, &Cwon, &Pwon);
    printf("num= %d Tie= %d Cwon= %d  Pwon= %d \n", num, Tie, Cwon, Pwon );

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
num= 0 Tie= 2 Cwon= 3  Pwon= 4 
num= 0 Tie= 3 Cwon= 4  Pwon= 5
```

Comment: if you value my help you can upvote my answer and accept it. I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
int scissors(int comp, int Tie, int Cwon, int Pwon);
```

this is passing it as value, In C, you need to pass the pointer to the memory address where the value Cwon, Pwon are stored in order to update it in a function. Something like:

```
int scissors(int comp, int *Tie, int *Cwon, int *Pwon);
```

and when you are passing your ints to the function you could simply add:

```
int scissors(comp, &Tie, &Cwon, &Pwon);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that all parameters in C are passed by value, this means that the parameter is copied to a local storage in the function and has nothing to do with the value you have in main.

There are two approaches to solve this problem:

- The first, most simple, is to make `Tie`, `Cwon`, and `Pwon` global variables, by declaring them outside of `main` or as any parameter in the parameter list, like this:

  ```
  int Tie, Cwon, Pwon;
  ```

  and use them in each routine as if they were the parameters.  This makes them global variables to which you can refer from each function in your program (from `main`, `scissors`, `stone` and `paper`)  You have to put the declaration at the beginning of the file, and you can even put initial values for each variable, as in:

  ```
  int Tie = 0, Cwon = 0, Pwon = 0;
  ```
- the second is more elaborate, as it requires you to know what is a reference (a pointer pointing to a variable) and passing the proper reference.  This means you have to change:

  ```
  int scissors(int comp, int Tie, int Cwon, int Pwon)
  ```

  to

  ```
  int scissors(int comp, int *Tie, int *Cwon, int *Pwon)
  ```

  but then, you have to pass the routine the actual references:

  ```
  int num_Ties = 0, num_Cwon = 0, num_Pwon = 0;

  ....

  scissors(comp, &num_Ties, &num_Cwon, &num_Pwon);
  ```

  this means you want to call `scissors` with the value of `comp` variable, and references to variables `num_Ties`, `num_Cwon` and `num_Pwon`.